# How I can use grid system of bootstrap in views-exposed-form.tpl.php?

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I have a form with filters exposed and I want to apply the bootstrap grid system for each input to adapt to different devices, but in the `views-exposed-form.tpl.php` I don't know how to access each generated input.